# Apache Airflow running orphaned dag from days ago

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-webserver

New to airflow, I was running a dag a few days ago on the scheduler. I want to kill it but it won't stop. I've uninstalled airflow and reinstalled, I have even created a new project just to start from scratch. Additionally, I have deleted all those files associated with the first project.

Every time I run the scheduler, after a minute of so this appears:

```
schedule_job_runner.py resetting orphaned tasks for active dags
```

And my old dag from days ago begins to run again.

I can't find anything in the `airflow.db` or can find any place where this being stored somewhere even though I'm deleting airflow and changing projects.

Could someone explain what is happening.